# How to give custom names as key and value property names to C# MongoDB driver DictionaryRepresantation.ArrayOfDocuments

Tags: c#, mongodb

I need to Serialize a C# class which has a Dictionary type property using BsonSerializer.

I use DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments, however it automatically gives  "k" and "v" to property name and generate something like this :

```
Field : [ 
   {"k" : "100","v" : "5"},
   {"k" : "200","v" : "2"}
]
```

But I want to generate this :

```
Field : [ 
   {"Point" : "100","Order" : "5"},
   {"Point" : "200","Order" : "2"}
]
```

How can I give this "Point" and "Order" name to property names ?
Thanks for any help

EDIT : Here is my class :

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
[Upsertable(typeof(Player))]
public class Player     {
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets PlayerId property of <see cref="Player"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    [BsonId]
    [UpsertableId]
    public int PlayerId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets PlayerName property of <see cref="Player"/> object.
    /// </summary>
    public string PlayerName{ get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets PointOrders property of <see cref="Player"/> object
    /// </summary>
    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public Dictionary<int, int> PointOrders{ get; set; }

}
```

I want to serialize PointOrders property as I mentioned above.

Comment: Could you please edit your question and paste the class you want to serialize?

Comment: Ok I added my question.